# SQLAlchemy ORM Relationship stopped working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I built an API using FastAPI, sqlalchemy, and pydantic. The ORM modeling was working great for some time, but I updated my code and broke the relational mapping somehow. Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong in my ORM mapping.

When I go to http://localhost:8000/test-rel I expect to see this:

```
[{"name":"P One","pk_id":1,"fk_id":1, "test":{"test_id":1, "test_name":"One"}},{"name":"P Two","pk_id":2,"fk_id":2, "test":{"test_id":2, "test_name":"Two"}},{"name":"P Three","pk_id":3,"fk_id":null, "test": null}]
```

but instead I see this:

```
[{"name":"P One","pk_id":1,"fk_id":1},{"name":"P Two","pk_id":2,"fk_id":2},{"name":"P Three","pk_id":3,"fk_id":null}]
```

Here is the test code portion of my project that I was using to troubleshoot:

**schemas.py**

```
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel

class Test(BaseModel):
    test_id: int
    test_name: str


class TestP(BaseModel):
    pk_id: int
    fk_id: Optional[int]
    name: Optional[str]

    test: Test

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

**models.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, DATE, DECIMAL
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from sql_app.database import Base

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = "test"

    test_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    test_name = Column(String)


class TestP(Base):
    __tablename__ = "test_p"

    pk_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    fk_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("test.test_id"), nullable=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=True)

    test = relationship("Test")
```

**database.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import urllib

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                                 "SERVER=SQLEXPRESS;"
                                 "DATABASE=Test;"
                                 "Trusted_Connection=yes")

engine = create_engine(
    "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params)
)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

**crud.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import and_, update, delete
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from typing import List

from sql_app import models
from sql_app import schemas

def test_rel(db: Session) -> List[schemas.TestP]:
    return db.query(models.TestP).all()
```

**main.py**

```
import babel.numbers as bn
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException, Request
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from sql_app import crud, models, schemas
from sql_app.database import SessionLocal, engine

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

app = FastAPI()

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

@app.get("/test-rel/")
def test_rel(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return crud.test_rel(db=db)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answered on github discussions by CaseIIT:**

A couple of things:

```
def test_rel(db: Session) -> List[schemas.TestP]:
    return db.query(models.TestP).all()
This returns a List[model.TestP]
```

Also the relationships are lazy loaded by default. Look at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html for the eager loading options

**My Response:**
This was exactly what I was looking for. I was unaware that relationships were lazy loaded by default. My code is using pydantic to validate the response and my queries were failing validation because the pydantic validation was not seeing the joined tables. I updated my code to add eager loading and it is now working exactly as I expect it to.

```
test = relationship("Test", lazy='joined')
```